# Autohotkey: toggle hold down a key with ControlSend

Tags: autohotkey

I'm attempting to make a script that holds down the F key in a specific program on a toggle.
I'm completely new to autohotkey (almost new to coding in general) and the issue I run into is the toggling doesn't work while I use "controlsend" but works fine with "send" so it essentially holds down the F key and locks up the app (normal keys stop working until I manually close the autohotkey script) and it never stops holding F but with "send" it works completely normal aka toggles fine.

This fails in the way described before:

````
  If GetKeyState("f")
    ControlSend, , {f Up}, Pal
  Else
    ControlSend, , {f Down}, Pal
Return```

The code that works while the window is active:
```$0::
  If GetKeyState("f")
    Send {f Up}
  Else
    Send {f Down}
Return```
````